# как лучше обращаться к tuple-подэлементу элемента массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например у меня есть массив

```
moves = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,2)]
```

Как правильно обращаться к каждому подэлементу элемента в массиве?

Просто когда я обращаюсь к ним так

```
for move in moves:
    for x, y in move: 
        ....
```

или так

```
for move in moves:
    x, y = move 
....
```

Мне выводит ошибку `cannot unpack non-iterable int object`

Comment: move не распаковывается, можете просто заменить на `x, y = move[0], move[1]`

Comment: Второй способ вообще-то работает, я даже проверил на всякий случай. А для первого нужен ещё один уровень вложенности данных.

Comment: @mmyš, вы ошибаетесь, код `x, y = move` вполне работает, и ваш `x, y = move[0], move[1]` ничем принципиально от него не отличается

Comment: @CrazyElf это у меня где-то, что то не так было

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант такой:

```
moves = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,2)] 

for x, y in moves: 
    print(x, y)
```

Ваш второй вариант тоже должен работать. Если вы пишете, что он не работает, то вы где-то что-то напутали.

Первый вариант не работает, потому что у вас один `move` - это один тапл. Это всё равно, как если бы вы написали

```
for x, y in (1, 2):
    ...
```

Этот код будет последовательно перебирать элементы тапла (сначала возьмёт 1, потом возьмёт 2) и каждый из этих элементов будет пытаться распаковать на две переменные. Очевидно, что одно отдельное число нельзя распаковать в две переменные, именно об этом и написано в ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

---

Кажется самый простой и удобный способ

```
for i in range(len(moves)):
        x, y = moves[i]
```

Comment: В Питоне не нужно и не рекомендуется использовать индексы: `for x, y in moves:` делает то же самое.